# The method execute() is undefined for the type Drive.Files.List

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

i just started using google drive API for java and i am using the same code as described on the site to retrieve file list from google drive but the method `execute` does not exists :( what should i do ?

```
  private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = service.files().list();

        do {
          try {
            FileList files = request.execute(); //The method execute() is undefined for the type Drive.Files.List

            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
          }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
                 request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

        return result;
      }
```

Comment: Often the example code is not up to date with the latest library version. Firstly make sure you have the latest library installed and then look to see what the equivalent method is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the road, so I can't elanborate on it. So, I just quickly chopped-off a piece of code that I know works.

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive _svc;
...
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List qry = 
                               _svc.files().list().setQ("trashed = false");
String npTok = null;
do {
  com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList gLst = qry.execute();
  for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File gFl : gLst.getItems()) { 
    String id = gFl.getId();
  }
  npTok = gLst.getNextPageToken();
  qry.setPageToken(npTok);
} while (npTok != null && npTok.length() > 0);
```

Good luck.